# How to generate Zipf-like samples, by using scripting language

Tags: shell-script, scripting, random

Is there any scripting language function (like in `python` or `bash`) that samples from a [zipf-like distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html), for exponent `0<a<=1`.

PS: I am aware of existence of [a numpy function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html) that can generate zipf samples, but it's only for `a >1`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the basic equations, how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
k = float(sys.argv[1])
s = float(sys.argv[2])
N = int(sys.argv[3])
def zipf(k, s, N):
    return (1/k**s) / sum(1/n**s for n in range(1, N+1))
print zipf(k, s, N)
```

Uses only builtin, basic routines in the language. Could be converted to just about any other language, e.g. `perl`, `ruby`.  Here is a version in `awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    for (n=1; n<=N; n++) {
        den=den+1/n^s;
    }
    print (1/(k^s))/den;
}
```

The `awk` script requires no input file, but does require variable assignments on the command line:

```
$ /tmp/zipf.awk -vk=10 -vs=4 -vN=10
9.24183e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a Python [expovariate distribution](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.expovariate), with the correct value of lambda, work?